# How to get the value of the progressBar of a busyIndicator in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, busyindicator

I would like to know how can I get the percentage value of a progress bar of a BusyIndiccator in silverlight?
I am new in using this control. 
I hope I can get the answer to my question.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? BusyIndicator has no value. It has the IsIndeterminate property of the ProgressBar set to true. You either set the IsBusy to true or false. Otherwise you need the ProgressBar control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BusyIndicator doesn't have a progressValue, it is just a visual element to show that something is happening.
However you can check the samples on how to change this :

```
 <controlsToolkit:HeaderedContentControl
                Grid.Column="2"
                Header="Custom Content"
                Style="{StaticResource SampleContainer}">
                <controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator
                    IsBusy="True"
                    DisplayAfter="0">
                    <controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="4" >
                                <TextBlock Text="Downloading Email" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <StackPanel Margin="4">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Downloading message 4/10..."/>
                                    <ProgressBar Value="40" Height="15"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Pause" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 2 0"/>
                                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2 0 0 0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
                    <controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator.OverlayStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#ffffeeee"/>
                        </Style>
                    </controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator.OverlayStyle>
                    <controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Style>
                    </controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
                    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource SampleContent}"/>
                </controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator>
            </controlsToolkit:HeaderedContentControl>
```

Link : [Silverlight samples](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html)

Comment: Thanks MBen! I'll check the link.